# How to test conditions in apache configuration?

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I want to test a configuration in apache. How can I "debug" the configuration file ?
For example, let's say that I have :

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
    GeoIPEnable On
    GeoIPDBFile PATH_TO_LIB\GeoIP.dat
    GeoIPEnableUTF8 On
    GeoIPOutput All
</IfModule>
```

Can i send a fake IP **locally** to the header ? (ie) Can I **locally** fake/spoff another IP than 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Have you tried apachectl -M or apache2ctl -M? This will tell you if the module has been loaded. Other than that, you could put something that Apache will not like, such as a purposely bad command and if apache spits out an error - it parsed the conf file. Just putting "TEST IF THIS LINE IS CALLED" as you have should result in a conf file parse error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now know that the line is called. (sorry can't uopvote the comment yet)

Comment: What is the actual module you are trying to load? Is it a standard apache mod?

Comment: I edited the question @Gmck 
It is GeoIP that I am trying (desperatly) to test locally.

Comment: You have to test from a public IP address, not a local one. TCP relies on a 3 way handshake to initialize requests. if you spoof your originating IP address, you will never get past the synchronization stage and no HTTP information will be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that configuration you can't (at least easily). I suggest for testing, you add this option:

`GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On`

From the documentation (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/#Proxy-Related_Directives)

> When this is set, the module will look at several other sources for the IP address, in this order:
>
> The HTTP_CLIENT_IP environment variable (set by Apache).
>
> The HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR environment variable (set by Apache).
>   The X-Forwarded-For for header (set by a proxy).
>
> The HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR environment variable (set by Apache).

Set that option for testing and remove it when done. Then you can send arbitrary IP's as HTTP headers with curl, ex:

`curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4" "http://your.site/path"`